# How to parse html using Sed in a batch file

Tags: html, parsing, batch-file, sed

Trying to parse an html using Sed code. My results seem to only return the first word when I search on the line containing the "Product Index".

Using the HTML from https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/L77HDE15SD1CH4RC309/L77HDE15SD1CH4RC309-ND I can return "D-Sub" although I want "D-Sub Connector". HTML.html is just the format I save the html in.

```
FOR /F "" %%A IN ('sed HTML.html -n -e "s/.*Product Index.*"".\(.*\)<.*/\1/p"') DO SET results=%%A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A
```

which should apply the entire line to %%A. As it is, you are using the default `tokens=1` and `delims=[separators]` which will assign the first string up to the first separator.

See `for /?` from the prompt for more documentation.

Comment: I've made the change and now receive an error of "& was unexpected at this time." @magoo

Comment: Not from the code you've posted, you didn't, unless there's something really screwy going on. The code should execute `SET results=D-Sub Connectors</a> &gt; Amphenol ICC (Commercial Products) L77HDE15SD1CH4RC309`.You could change your `sed` instruction to drop all characters including and following `<`, or simply change `delims=` to `delims=<` and have `for` do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Including `delims=<` fixed my issue and the code works great now. @magoo